# Azure Migration Project to CosmosDB throws error `Unspecificed`

Tags: azure, mongodb

I'm trying to migrate my Mongodb server to Azure Cosmos. I've created a migration service in Azure Database Migration Services and I'm trying to create a project with the following settings:

```
Source server name: my server
Server port: 27017
User Name: user
Password: password
```

I'm getting an error, a connectivity one it seems. I think there shouldn't be any connectivity issue according to my setup but I think the error is more due to some information missing, maybe in the migration service?

The error traces begin with issues like:

```
Error type
Failed to connect, please check error details
Error Detail
The connection timed out. Possible reasons for this include
the address and/or port was not correct or the server is not running.
A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using 
CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, 
LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }.
Client view of  cluster state is { ClusterId : "2", ConnectionMode : "Automatic",
Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : 
[{ ServerId: 
"{ ClusterId : 2, EndPoint : "Unspecified/<my server>:27017" }",
EndPoint: "Unspecified/<my server>:27017"
```

I don't understand where that `Unspecified` comes from. I suppose is something that I haven't configured, but I don't know what needs to be configured to get rid of this error.

I've checked the network traffic of the requests sent to Azure and I've seen that
on the requests to `/services/MigrationServiceMongo/projects/MigrationMongoTest/tasks/SqlConnect...`
we are receiving as input something that has the `dataSource` populated as it should be, but the `serverName` is empty. I guess that is related as well.

Any ideas?